# ContentEditable span inside label element looses focus when click on content editable span

Tags: html, contenteditable

I Observe the following issue with content editable. When place inside the label element it looses the focus when click on the content editable span.

Please refer to below code.

```
<label>
<span contenteditable="true"> this is my text</span>
<input type="textbox" onfocus="console.log('hello')"/>
</label>
```

When you click on the contenteditable span the focus is automatically shifted to the next input.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small hack to solve the loosing the focus issue from content editable. You need to wrap the contenteditable span inside the label and the problem is solve.

```
<label>
<label>
<span contenteditable="true"> this is my text</span>
</label>
<input type="textbox" onfocus="console.log('hello')"/>
</label>
```